# what's the difference between "undoubtedly" and "naturally"?

Tags: word-choice

> The experts still have a long way to go to explore new sources of energy. **Naturally**, they have to work even harder.

Can I use "undoubtedly" in this sentence instead of "naturally"?

Comment: You can choose from a range of alternative "affirmatory adverbs" *(certainly, clearly, evidently, plainly, of course, undeniably, unquestionably, without doubt,...)* with effectively the same meaning in such contexts. In most cases it would be splitting hairs to claim some *semantic* distinction between any of them.

Comment: In such contexts, that initial adverb is effectively an emphatic version of "consequential" conjunctions like ***so, thus, hence, therefore***, but note that from another perspective they're "sentence adverbs" (which can also be placed at the ***end*** of the sentence, and sometimes embedded ***within*** it).